# TYPO3 Upgrade vom 11.2.0 to 11.5.0 - Problems with Form Extension and EXT: path in Frontend

Tags: typo3, content-management-system, typo3-11.x

I have upgraded a TYPO3 installation from 11.2.0 to the latest version of today 11.5.0.

After changing my symlinks to the new TYPO3 source files, cleaning all caches, performing all upgrade wizards successfully and without errors, I get 2 new error messages that I haven't seen in previous TYPO3 installations. One in the backend and one in the frontend.

Frontend:

### 503 - Resource paths must start with "EXT:" and must reference Resources/Public

[image]

and in the Backend:

### 503 - TYPO3.CMS.Form.mixins.formElementMixins.FormElementMixin does not exist within the configuration

[image]

I am currently finding out the source of the problem. Since Google has no content about these new issues, I thought it would be a good idea to create this thread.

Does anyone have similar problems upgrading to TYPO3 11.5.0?

Comment: See [Bug #95495] (https://forge.typo3.org/issues/95495)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for the second problem? I'm currently facing the same issue (T3 11.5.19)

Comment: Ok, just found the culprit. I used `mixins.formElementMixins.BaseCollectionEditorsMixin` in my form-finisher yaml. This doesn't work anymore as described on this page https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/main/en-us/I/Concepts/Finishers/Index.html - Any ideas?

Comment: TYPO3.CMS.Form.mixins.* are deprecated in v11 and removed in v12:
https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.2/Deprecation-89742-FormMixins.html

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to the frontend error message **Resource paths must start with "EXT:" and must reference Resources/Public** myself after looking deeper into the error messages.

I included a SASS file for the bootstrap_package like this in my setup:

```
page{
    includeCSS{
        custom = EXT:my_package/Resources/Private/Scss/style.scss
    }
}
```

After I changed "Private" to "Public", the error message disappeared.

```
page{
    includeCSS{
        custom = EXT:my_package/Resources/Public/Scss/style.scss
    }
}
```

Conclusion: Apparently TYPO3 now makes sure that your resource paths are named the right way and do NOT point to any other directory.

Comment: I guess with https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/71457 this will be improved as well

Answer (score 2):

New in TYPO3 12 is that all outgoing mails are sent with sysMail/fluidMail.

If you have the following setting in your backend:

Settings-> Extension Configuration ->  backend -> logo

An individual logo for the login area of the TYPO3 backend,
this logo can be retrieved also e.g. from fileadmin, and it will work for the login area.

**But if form is sending a Sysmail as a finisherin the core extension form (that is what form is doing as a preset) then tries to use this logo placed in the header of the fluid-sys-mail and in this case it can only come from an extension (or sitepackage) EXT: ...**

If you have set a fileadmin file as a logo you will get an TYPO3 error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).